# How to get distinct values from array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique, distinct

Assuming I have the following:

var array =

```
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":null, "date":"1959-08-10", "home":"ny"}
],
[
    {"name":"Bill", "age":null, "date":"1956-08-10", "home":"tx"}
],
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":"17", "date":null, "home":"ny"}
],
[
    {"name":null, "age":"17", "date":"1956-08-10", "home":"tx"}
],
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":"17", "date":"1959-08-10", "home":null}
]
```

What is the best way to be able to get an new array:

var new_array =

```
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":"17", "date":"1959-08-10", "home":"ny"}
],
[
    {"name":"Bill", "age":"17", "date":"1956-08-10", "home":"tx"}
]
```

Comment: How are you going to decide which to choose when you have multiple objects with the same name?

Comment: like this: (name == (name || null)) && (age == (age || null)) && (date == (date || null)) && (home == (home || null))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically four options available to you: A regular loop, or the map, filter, reduce functions on the array instance, for example:

```
var oldArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var newArray = oldArray.filter((item) => item > 2); // Gives you [3, 4, 5]
```

Have a look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for a more specific description. This link is to filter, but map and reduce can be found in the left sidepanel.

*Edit*
The loop method:

```
var oldArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var newArray = [];

for (var item of oldArray) {
  if (item > 2) {
    newArray.push(item);
  }
}
newArray; // Gives you [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bill and Joe are the reference points.
You need to loop through the array and test for name and store (in another array) non-null values.
Also, are there only two names?
You probably need to allow for a variable number of names.
this is far from complete code but will hopefully get you started.
Also look at [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
You need to at least show what you have tried to make discussion and debug easier!

```
var dataCollect=[];
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {    
    if (array[i]['name'] != null) { name = array[i]['name'];
    /* then your range of qualifiers gets complicated
eg. array[3] has no name so how to know what this relates to?
you probably need another internal loop to test !=null
to get values for x y z */
    dataCollect.push ({
name: name,
age: 'x',
date: 'y',
home: 'z'
    });
}
```

Please offer some code to show how you have tried to work with this.

Comment: In case of array methods, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would work better, since it will return new filtered array with no need to create and fill it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have the following:

var array =

```
[
    {"numberUnique1":"123456789", "numberUnique2":null, "name":null, "date":"1959-08-10", "kinship":null}
],
[
    {"numberUnique1":"987654123", "numberUnique2":"15935478", "name":"Joe", "date":null, "kinship":null}
],
[
    {"numberUnique1":"123456789", "numberUnique2":"258369147", "name":null, "date":"1959-08-10", "kinship":null}
],
[
    {"numberUnique1":null, "numberUnique2":"15935478", "name":null, "date":"1976-09-14", "kinship":"dad"}
],
[
    {"numberUnique1":"123456789", "numberUnique2":null, "name":"Bill", "date":"1959-08-10", "kinship":"son"}
]
```

What is the best way to be able to get an new array:

var new_array =

```
[
    {"numberUnique1":"123456789", "numberUnique2":258369147, "name":"Bill", "date":"1959-08-10", "kinship":"son"}
],
[
    {"numberUnique1":"987654123", "numberUnique2":"15935478", "name":"Joe", "date":"1976-09-14", "kinship":"dad"}
]
```

It was solved like this (I don't know if there is a better way):

```
new_array = [];
if (array.length > 0) {
    new_array.push(array[0]);
    let aux = 1;
    let qtd = 0;
    m:for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < aux; ii++) {
            if ( (new_array[ii].numberUnique1 != array[i].numberUnique1) && (!!new_array[ii].numberUnique1) && (!!array[i].numberUnique1) ) {
                for (var iii = 0; iii < new_array.length; iii++) {
                    if (new_array[iii].numberUnique1 == array[i].numberUnique1) {
                        qtd = qtd + 1;
                    }
                }
                if (qtd == 0) {    
                    new_array.push(array[i]);
                    if ( (new_array.length < array.length) ) {
                        aux = aux + 1;
                        continue m;
                    }
                }
            } else if ( (new_array[ii].numberUnique1 == array[i].numberUnique1) && (!!new_array[ii].numberUnique1) && (!!array[i].numberUnique1) ) {
                if ( (!new_array[ii].numberUnique2) &&  (!!array[i].numberUnique2) ) {
                    new_array[ii].numberUnique2 = array[i].numberUnique2;
                }
                if ( (!new_array[ii].name) &&  (!!array[i].name) ) {
                    new_array[ii].name = array[i].name;
                }
                if ( (!new_array[ii].date) &&  (!!array[i].date) ) {
                    new_array[ii].date = array[i].date;
                }
                if ( (!new_array[ii].kinship) &&  (!!array[i].kinship) ) {
                    new_array[ii].kinship = array[i].kinship;
                }
            } else {
                if ( (new_array[ii].numberUnique2 != array[i].numberUnique2) && (!!new_array[ii].numberUnique2) && (!!array[i].numberUnique2) ) {
                    for (var iii = 0; iii < new_array.length; iii++) {
                        if (new_array[iii].numberUnique2 == array[i].numberUnique2) {
                            qtd = qtd + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (qtd == 0) {    
                        new_array.push(array[i]);
                        if ( (new_array.length < array.length) ) {
                            aux = aux + 1;
                            continue m;
                        }
                    }
                } else if ( (new_array[ii].numberUnique2 == array[i].numberUnique2) && (!!new_array[ii].numberUnique2) && (!!array[i].numberUnique2) ) {
                    if ( (!new_array[ii].numberUnique1) &&  (!!array[i].numberUnique1) ) {
                        new_array[ii].numberUnique1 = array[i].numberUnique1;
                    }
                    if ( (!new_array[ii].name) &&  (!!array[i].name) ) {
                        new_array[ii].name = array[i].name;
                    }
                    if ( (!new_array[ii].date) &&  (!!array[i].date) ) {
                        new_array[ii].date = array[i].date;
                    }
                    if ( (!new_array[ii].kinship) &&  (!!array[i].kinship) ) {
                        new_array[ii].kinship = array[i].kinship;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( (new_array[ii].name != array[i].name) && (!!new_array[ii].name) && (!!array[i].name) ) {
                        for (var iii = 0; iii < new_array.length; iii++) {
                            if (new_array[iii].name == array[i].name) {
                                qtd = qtd + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        if (qtd == 0) {    
                            new_array.push(array[i]);
                            if ( (new_array.length < array.length) ) {
                                aux = aux + 1;
                                continue m;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ( (new_array[ii].name == array[i].name) && (!!new_array[ii].name) && (!!array[i].name) ) {
                        if ( (new_array[ii].date == array[i].date) && (!!new_array[ii].date) && (!!array[i].date) ) {
                            if ( (new_array[ii].kinship == array[i].kinship) && (!!new_array[ii].kinship) && (!!array[i].kinship) ) {
                                if ( (!new_array[ii].numberUnique1) &&  (!!array[i].numberUnique1) ) {
                                    new_array[ii].numberUnique1 = array[i].numberUnique1;
                                }
                                if ( (!new_array[ii].numberUnique2) &&  (!!array[i].numberUnique2) ) {
                                    new_array[ii].numberUnique2 = array[i].numberUnique2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested your solution but guess that it is working. Well done! The variety of variables does make this a fairly complex matter - hence the layering of your if, else, else if... Interesting that you have reconfigured your array. This is the value of trying a solution against your own question - sometimes rephrasing the question leads to an answer. Perhaps part of your solution could be better filtering at the input stage? See you around here some more :)